# want to share a string among multiple instances in C#

Tags: c#, shared-memory

I want to share a string among multiple instances of application in C#.
I am using .net framework 3.5 SP1. and this version **does not support Memory-Mapped Files**.

 I can not use Disk IO because of some permission and performance issues.
so can anyone tell me a convenient way to do this.
I searched and came across some of them:
1. Serialization
2. Marshaling
3. Pipes
but all of these are too complicated  to share just one string.

thanks

Comment: You probably mean *process instances*? In that case use any kind of IPC.

Comment: @Cicada - You may have noticed the OP has already shot down most forms of IPC.

Comment: @Oded I did notice. There's still quite a lot of choice (unless OP find them too complex, in which case this question is not answerable).

Comment: @Cicada  yes i mean multiple process instances i edited my question also

Comment: Maybe tell us what is the real problem to which you found solution with sharing a string.

Comment: Also, having some information about the context would be useful: what kind of string (small or huge), what about security, how many instances...

Comment: @DavidBrabant string is small(max 10 characters) no. of instances <=100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a database.

If you want shared memory I think one of the things you'll run into is AppDomains see here: Here is an example to get around that: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17606/NET-Interprocess-Communication

Comment: If he doesn't want to use a full blown Sql Server instance, he could think about something like SqlLite or MS Sql Server Compact.

Answer (score 1):

[message queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), maybe?

Check [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-microsoft-message-queuing-in-c-for-inter-process-communication/6170794) article for an example

Comment: Waiting for OP to complain that they are either too complicated or that they have permission issue precluding them from using this solution.

Comment: @ToggleButton - When you start off your question asking for solutions and immediately telling people what they can't suggest, you make it near impossible to answer it.

Comment: @ToggleButton - That makes it a poll question (asking for multiple views). This kind of question is not suitable for Stack Overflow, as detailed in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) as "Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site"

Comment: @Oded FAQ also says that - "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." that is why i putted constraints.